# set mediaPlayer Volume dynamically while playing sound

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I am having an application in which I am playing a sound with the help of MediaPlayer in a service,which is running properly. But what I want is to set the volume of the sound with the help of seekBar or something dynamically while the sound is being played.
The code is as follow:

PlayerActivity:

```
   public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");

      startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");

      stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
```

MyService.java

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        player.start();
    }
```

How would I set a seekbar and set the volume of sound while it is playing.
Thanks.

Comment: u can use setOnSeekBarChangeListener on SeekBar

Comment: @Sam I tried that but it is not working with mediaplayer volume,if I change the volume of media player in onProgressChanged() method.

Comment: can u post those code.'